# User Control Connection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have created the kiosk system with several user controls and need to connect the hotdrinks user control using a button which is in the colddrinks user control.

When I use the following code it displays the both user controls together and hotdrinks displays under the colddrinks.I need to hide colddrinks first and display hotdrinks next.
I think need to use child and parent connection here, but didn't know how to do that. Please help me.

```
OrderTakingMenu ordertakingmenu;
HotDrinks hotDrinks;

public UserControl currentPanel;

public ColdDrink(OrderTakingMenu ordertakingmenuIn)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 100);
    ordertakingmenu = ordertakingmenuIn;
}

private void btnHotDrinks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    removePreviousPanel();
    currentPanel = new HotDrinks(ordertakingmenu);
    this.Controls.Add(currentPanel);
}

private void removePreviousPanel()
{
    this.Controls.Remove(currentPanel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Visible property.  First add both user controls on the form, and have them overlap each other (both at the same location, same size).

```
public ColdDrink(OrderTakingMenu ordertakingmenuIn)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 100);
    ordertakingmenu = ordertakingmenuIn;
    coldDrinksPanel.Visible = true;
    hotDrinksPanel.Visible = false;
}

private void btnHotDrinks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hotDrinksPanel.Visible = true;
    coldDrinksPanel.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this reply and it is not working and it display the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when its running. Thank you for your help and please give me your ideas.

Comment: Add both user controls added to the designer.   That will create them.   Make sure you don't access them before the call to InitializeComponent().